# Selecting only first 'n' characters of an Element with Linq to XML

Tags: c#, list, linq, linq-to-xml

The following line of code gives me a List with all timezones.

```
List<string> _timeZones = xdoc.Descendants("TimeZone").Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

However, in this particular list I would rather have the first 11 characters only.

Does someone know how to include this in the above Linq statement?

Thank you very much for your help,

Joey

Comment: Just add `SubString(0, 11)` to the end of Value?

Comment: @maccettura List<string> _hours = xdoc.Descendants("Hour").Select(x => x.Value.Substring(0, 11)).ToList(); This gives me an ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

Comment: Sounds like you have some values that are less than 11 characters... So try padding right first?  `PadRight(11).SubString(0, 11)`

Comment: @maccettura No, the lowest number is 29 and the highest is 61. I do have special characters there such as brackets, dash's and semicolons. Could this be of influence?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `Substring` but limit it to the length:

```
List<string> _timeZones = xdoc.Descendants("TimeZone").Select(x => x.Value.Substring(0, Math.Min(11, x.Value.Length))).ToList();
```

Comment: Need to add an additional closing bracket on the select statement and it then works like a charm. Thank You Very Much!!

Comment: Sorry about the typo - I apparently really can't type code into a SO box.